# BigQuery data transfer not recognizing wild card storage object names

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have setup a data transfer service in Google cloud to move data from JSON files in storage buckets to BigQuery table. The files in storage buckets have the same name prefix but have different date based suffixes. I have used gs://bucket_name/filename*.json as the
Cloud Storage URI in the transfer service configuration. The service seems to run fine when tried the first time. But subsequent runs with the same set of files completes with the error "No files found matching: "gs://bucket_name/filename*.json"". I don't see any other errors in the logs. I am trying this for the first time and need to schedule multiple such transfer service configurations. Any clue on why this is not working?

Comment: I have done multiple big data transfers have seen the message "No files found matching:" only when the file related to one specified in the transfer is not present. The transfer will not fail but just complete with the message. Are you sure the files are present in cloud storage? or the file name in cloud storage URI matches to the ones present in cloud storage? I have not seen any other reason why it would give no files found matching if the files are there. I tried from my end and did some transfers for URI "gs://test_776/example_*.json" and it worked and with no files I get the above messag

Comment: My understanding was the same that it is supposed to work just fine. It did work fine when I invoked it manually. But when I invoked it again with the same set of files in the source bucket, it through this message in the log. Not sure if it is because it recognized the same set of files. In any case, I haven't seen this message in the logs after I set it up to run on a daily schedule and after I made sure the files get moved to a different folder after processing. I will mark this as resolved for the time being.

Comment: ok,glad that this is resolved:-)

Comment: Since this is the top result in Google currently, I'd like to add that for me having slashes (`/`) in the path also broke the globbing and I kept getting `No files found matching:` straight from the beginning. Replacing the slashes with underscores made it work.